# AutoMapper ConstructServicesUsing is ignored

Tags: automapper

I have a Person and a PersonViewModel. I created a map from Person => PersonViewModel. The problem is that **PersonViewModel's only constructor needs an argument** (it has a dependency that I want to be injected) and AutoMapper is complaining because it says it needs a parameterless constructor.

To fix it, I used the ConstructServicesUsing method, but I haven't been successful with it :(

To illustrate the case, I created a test for you to see what I'm doing. It's pretty simple:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConstructServicesUsing()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(FactoryMethod);
            configuration.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var person = new Person();
        var personViewModel = Mapper.Map<Person, PersonViewModel>(person);
    }

    private object FactoryMethod(Type type)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is the classes and interface definitions. They are almost empty.

```
public class SomeyDependency : ISomeDependency
{
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency service;

    public PersonViewModel(ISomeDependency service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeDependency
{
}
```

As you see, I provide AutoMapper with a FactoryMethod, but it never get called.

When it reaches the last line of the test (Mapper.Map<...>()) it throws an excepton saying:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

Mapping types:
Person -> PersonViewModel
MappingWithContainerTests.Person -> MappingWithContainerTests.PersonViewModel

Destination path:
PersonViewModel

Source value:
MappingWithContainerTests.Person ---> System.ArgumentException: Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args
Parameter name: type
```

What's the problem?
Why isn't the FactoryMethod being called?

Comment: I know it's a bit older question but on the CreateMap<> there is a _.ConstructUsingServiceLocator()_ which should do the job, but in my case it's not working.

Comment: @khorvat +1, adding the .ConstructUsingServiceLocator() behind the CreateMap<> expression made it work for me and my case looks very similar to the example of the OP. Somehow, I expected that the mapper will always use the factory method, if provided. However, I wonder why it does not work for you though.

Answer (score 1):

As @khorvat mention where is missing `.ConstructUsingServiceLocator()`, for concrete mapping.

Also you can set constructor directly by

```
.ConstructUsing(source => Method(source.anySourceOptions))
```

Or as exception said:

> PersonViewModel, must have a constructor with 0 args or only optional
>   args. You have only one constructor with 1 not optional argument

you may create one more constructor without args:

```
public PersonViewModel()
{
    this.service = new SomeDependency();
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem.

Comment: It is. Then map one class to another it calls the constructor and create new object. So mapper does not know how he must call constructor with parameters. So options is: 1) Use constructor without parameters. 2) Say mapper take paramether from sorce - .ConstructUsing(source => new PersonViewModel(source.service) 3) Pass paramether directly - same like 2, but u can get it from IoC container if u have it, for example .ConstructUsing(source => new PersonViewModel(_kernel.Get<ISomeDependency>)

Comment: Adding another constructor just for the purposes of mapping is not an option: a) new constructor may affect existing design; b) class code may be unavailable for change.

Comment: Since design already needs a constructor without arguments which hidden in automapper it does not matter, it's will not work without it. Another option is set constructor directly by ConsructUsing or not use automapper.

Comment: By the way - post edited after my answer. And it's meaning changes to "Why isn't the FactoryMethod being called?", the answer is given by @khorvat, fully right - ".ConstructUsingServiceLocator()" missing.

Comment: this is the only correct answer, and (seems to be) the only answer on SO addressing DI in the entity's constructor. looks like a fundamental flaw in the Mapper, although that dirty workaround with explicit `.ConstructUsingServiceLocator()` works.

Comment: ...and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49117686/1426685) is related

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.

This does not work for me (Same error as yours):

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
         CreateMap<Context, MainViewModel>()
             .ReverseMap()
             .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
    }
}
```

But this does work:

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
         CreateMap<Context, MainViewModel>()
             .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()
             .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I still do not fully understand the cause.