# Configuring AutoMapper to Use AutoFac

Tags: automapper, autofac

I've configured AutoMapper to, I thought, use AutoFac to create object instances by defining the following AutoFac Module:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load( ContainerBuilder builder )
    {
        base.Load( builder );

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( assemblies )
            .Where( t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom( t ) && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsPublic )
            .As<Profile>();

        builder.Register( c => new MapperConfiguration( cfg =>
            {
                //cfg.ConstructServicesUsing( CSContainer.Instance.Resolve );
                foreach( var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>() )
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile( profile );
                }
            } ) )
            .AsSelf()
            .AutoActivate()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register( c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper( c.Resolve ) )
            .As<IMapper>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

I then created AutoMapper Profiles such as the following:

```
public class CommunityScannerManagerAutoMapProfile : Profile
{
    public CommunityScannerManagerAutoMapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CommunityUser, CommunityUserModel>()
            //.ConstructUsing(src => new CommunityUserModel(CSContainer.Instance.Resolve<IValidationService>()))
            .ForMember( dest => dest.VaultKey, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.VaultKeyName ) )
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Community, CommunityModel>()
            //.ConstructUsing(src=>new CommunityModel(CSContainer.Instance.Resolve<IValidationService>(  )))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ScannerConfiguration, CommunitiesModel>()
            .ForMember( dest => dest.Communities, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.Communities ) )
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

The destination types form a hierarchy: CommunitiesModel contains a collection of CommunityModel objects, and each CommunityModel object contains a collection of CommunityUserModel objects. The collections are mapped thru the AutoMapper Profile I created.

Each destination type -- CommunitiesModel, CommunityModel, and CommunityUserModel -- has constructor parameters which are registered with AutoFac (they themselves are also registered with AutoFac). So I thought AutoMapper would be able to resolve the instances it needed, calling upon AutoFac to create them.

But that's not the case. Unless I include those two commented out lines in the AutoMapper Profile class -- the ones starting with ConstructUsing -- I get an exception, from AutoMapper, that it can only handle classes with constructors that have no parameters, or only optional ones. Which implies AutoMapper is not using AutoFac to resolve/create those instances, contrary to what I expected.

Interestingly, AutoMapper has no problem creating instances of CommunitiesModel, the top level object, even though it, too, only has a constructor containing a parameter. So AutoMapper is using AutoFac for top level objects, but not the child objects.

Is there a global configuration I can set in AutoMapper to tell it to always use AutoFac? I tried using ConstructServicesUsing in configuring AutoMapper (the line is commented out in the code here), but it didn't seem to have any effect.

**Update**

Apparently, AutoMapper doesn't use DI to create objects "internally" (see @Lucian's comment).

But I noticed AutoMapper does support a ConstructUsing() clause, which allows you to tie it into a DI container like AutoMap:

```
CreateMap<CommunityUser, CommunityUserModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => CSContainer.Instance.Resolve<CommunityUserModel>())
    .ForMember( dest => dest.VaultKey, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.VaultKeyName ) )
    .ReverseMap();
```

So a related/follow-on question is: is there a way to make this the behavior without having to add the line to every CreateMapper() call where it applies?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. DI is only used for resolvers and converters. See [here](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html).

Comment: Good to know, thanx, @LucianBargaoanu. Would you mind giving me some feedback on the related question I put in the Update?

Comment: ForAllMaps would help with that.